# Can a transaction be successful in a 2-node private Stellar Network?

Tags: stellar-core, scp, stellar-laboratory, private-network

I have a 2-node private network running, when I try to submit a transaction using an XDR generated from the Stellar Lab, it first shows up as "PENDING", then one of the node stops working.

Any idea, why would this be happening?

This is how the stellar-core.cfg looks, with modified keys:

```
# simple configuration for a standalone test "network"
# see stellar-core_example.cfg for a description of the configuration parameters

HTTP_PORT=11626
PUBLIC_HTTP_PORT=true
RUN_STANDALONE=true
LOG_FILE_PATH=""

NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="Standalone Test Network ; Oct 2018"

NODE_SEED="SCNNL6IKBNRINHHXE3W2SO6RLKIU2Q2WHCGBQEZIW74SPBTZJTNBVO7M zagg-node01"
NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true

KNOWN_PEERS=["127.0.0.1:11635"]

#DATABASE="postgresql://dbname=stellar user=postgres password=password host=localhost"
#DATABASE="sqlite3://stellar.db"
DATABASE="postgresql://dbname=stellar_node01_db host=localhost user=stellar_node_user password=testdb"


#Bucket directory path
BUCKET_DIR_PATH = "buckets"

PEER_PORT=11625

COMMANDS=["ll?level=trace"]

FAILURE_SAFETY=0
UNSAFE_QUORUM=true
#The public keys of the Stellar testnet servers
[QUORUM_SET]

THRESHOLD_PERCENT=100
VALIDATORS=["$zagg-node01"]

[HISTORY.vs]
get="cp tmp/stellar-core/history/vs/{0} {1}"
put="cp {0} tmp/stellar-core/history/vs/{1}"
mkdir="mkdir -p tmp/stellar-core/history/vs/{0}"
```

Comment: where does the "PENDING" comes from? Lab or Horizon or Core or..?

and...how did the node stop? Could you check if it was Core, Horizon or VM died out?

Comment: I am not using Horizon, it is not in the picture, I am generating the XDR from the lab and then passing to the URL, localhost:11626/tx?blob=XDR. 11626 is my node 1, and it is getting stopped with the following message:
    terminate caller after throwing an instance of 'soci:soci_error' //
      what():   Cannot bind to (by name) :v11   //
    Aborted (core dumped)  //

Comment: Could you also provide the Core version number and also stellar-core.cfg (without the exact keys)? still not sure with too little info

Comment: I added the stellar-core.cfg (without the exact keys), not sure about the core version number, where can I find that?

Comment: information too vague to proceed... just one wonder: you want both nodes to be `VALIDATORS`, or just the 1st node?

Comment: Both are validators

Comment: but there's only one element in the array: `VALIDATORS=["$zagg-node01"]`. Probrably you should put something like `VALIDATORS=["$zagg-node01", "$zagg-node02"]` but you have to reference the zagg-node02 at `NODE_NAMES`